# Some users cannot update to our crosswalk android app

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

We release a new update for our android app. In this update we integrated crosswalk webview into our app. We follow the document and upload two APK files(ARM & X86) to play store and make a staged rollout to 10% of the market. Since then we receive a lot of negative feedbacks.

These are some of the feedback: 
'Package file not correct', 
'invalid package file', 
"Your app whats to update but when it gets to 100% downloaded, it zeros out and starts the download over again repeatedly"
"Fake file won't even download! Gets to 96% then restarts downloading again."

The devices so far includes:
Galaxy Note3
Galaxy S3 
Galaxy S4

Some of them do clear play store cache, but no luck.

Any idea how to solve this problem? (The APK works fine on our testing phones).